# How do I horizontally distribute text with equal spacing?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, typography, text, white-space

How do I horizontally distribute text in Illustrator so that it has equal spacing between the words? When I use the horizontal distribution tool it doesn't give equal spacing between words.

Comment: How are you doing the horizontal distribution because it should work. Are your words in a bounding box? If so that might be the issue

Comment: Are they individual words/objects OR are you trying to space words within a text box?

Answer (score 3):

If your text is point text, or individual text objects, just use the **Distribute Spacing** options on the **Align Panel**

[image: align panel]

You may need to choose `Show Options` from the Align Panel Menu to see the distribute spacing items.

Answer (score 0):

Other than breaking the text up and distributing groups or letters/words, the justification panel might be able to help:

[image]

[image]

Other software like Corel Draw might be able to provide a better solution, though.

Comment: Just tried this and it still doesn't have equal spaces, thanks for your reply though!

Comment: It requires Full Justify (the extreme right icon). Left Justify would have no effect.